# How can we update the data in wordcloud Highchart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am not able to update the data in wordcloud highchart when my data is coming from  websocket service.Can you please help to figure out.
This is my sample code.
[sam](https://codepen.io/nikhil593/pen/jxxMqQ)

```
    let cloudData =
    [{
        "name": "time",
        "weight": 342
    }, {
        "name": "radicals",
        "weight": 4
    }, {
        "name": "conceived",
        "weight": "4"
    }];
let dt = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'wordcloud',
        data: cloudData,
        name: 'tags',
        point: {
            events: {
            }

        }
    }],

});

$('#button').click(function () {

    dt.series[0].data[0].update({"name": "word", "weight": "5"});
    dt.redraw();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="button">Update first point</button>
```

Comment: check this way to  update https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QrrpMY

Comment: I can see that the update in your sample work - in another fiddle it also works https://jsfiddle.net/rc08ohdc/